# How to validate the optional field?

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests, testng

As per the requirements, "XYZ" field is mandatory field, but this field is optional in the form which I am testing. 
"XYZ" is a text field. So when I automate the form, whether that field is empty or filled it passes. In reality, this test should fail. 
I am using TestNG and selenium.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Isnt that a bug in the Web design? If XYZ should be mandatory and is optional, you should raise a bug and get it solved...

Comment: @Pavel Janicek-Agreed. Tested manually and raised a bug. How should I automate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the text field empty, click on `Submit` to submit the form.
Check for any validations `"Please enter text here."` or `"1 missed field"`.
if the the validation alert is not seen, the test script will fail and that is how you will catch it.

Think of selenium as a way to replicate a real user click through on a website. So when manually clicking through, you clicked to submit the form and went to the next page when you actually expected a validation alert.

Comment: Thanks!! After clicking Submit button I will put an assertAlert command and the test will fail.

Comment: When I click on submit button, It throws an alert stating that "The form was not submitted because the following required fields are missing: XYZ" Please help me with "regex" in this statement.

Comment: What did you come up with so far?

Comment: I did it with regex but still the alert comes when I run my test for 1 time then it doesn't turn up. I think there must be some problem with configuration of form.